# PHP Sorting in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a very newbie question. But how would I sort the results of this alphabetically so the names in the li list are in order?

```
<?php 
// FOR THE CATEGORIES (PRODUCT TYPE)
$terms_one = get_terms('product_cat');
$count_one = count($terms_one);  
$i_one = 0; 

echo '<ul class="submenu one filter option-set" data-filter-group="gem-type">';
echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-filter-value="" class="selected">ALL</a>';

if ($count_one > 0) {        
foreach ($terms_one as $term_one) 
{
    $i_one++;      
    $term_list_one .= '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-filter-value=".'. $term_one->slug .'"> <span>'. $term_one->count .'</span>'. $term_one->name .'</a></li>';

    if ($count_one != $i_one) 
    {
        $term_list_one .= '';
        } else {
        $term_list_one .= '';
    }
} 
  echo $term_list_one;
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in an array with arguments in the `get_terms()` function, `orderby` and `order` are probably what you want.

Here's the documentation:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Answer (score 1):

```
$terms_one = get_terms('product_cat','orderby=FIELD&order=ASC');
```

More information, you can refer to the documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thanks Jamie. That is what I was using. When it didn't work I thought I must be doing it wrong. I'm trying to sort http://jigoshop.com/ categories. Perhaps they do something tricky that doesn't allow to sort?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
asort($terms_one);
```

before doing the `foreach` loop.

If you want to sort by the array-key you can use `ksort()` ...